# Query Access with wildcard

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb, wildcard

i am trying to do a substring search from an access 2010 database in winforms.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchTerm", searchTerm);
command.CommandText = "SELECT [OA_Name] FROM [Operating_Authority_Table] WHERE [OA_Name] = [@%searchTerm%]";
```

I tried to do a full string search and able to do just that, but I can't get any successful searches when i change the term to be a substring.

am i implementing the wildcard character wrongly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchTerm", searchTerm); 
command.CommandText = "SELECT [OA_Name] FROM [Operating_Authority_Table] WHERE [OA_Name] = '%' + @searchTerm + '%'";
```

Comment: btw to people who might have similar problems, I have tried and found that '%' works, '*' did not work.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I'll edit that out of my answer.  % works across pretty much all major DB's (SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, etc).  For some reason I was thinking Access was special.

Comment: Access *is* special; it does use the asterisk as a wildcard character in its "traditional" dialect of SQL, but it also supports another syntax that is compliant with the ansi-92 standard.

Comment: @phoog: it's so-called [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0) is **not** compliant with the SQL-92 Standard, not even at entry level. MS claim it "conforms closely", a subjective view that I refute strongly. Also, the same documentation claims all kinds of things about the Access engine that are demonstrably untrue! Also see my answer about using `ALIKE` (which is "special" to Access) rather than `LIKE`.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer:

```
"...WHERE [OA_Name] = '%' + @searchTerm + '%'";
```

This will treat the `%` characters as text literals.

I was slightly surprised because the word "Wildcard" in the question title suggests the intent is for pattern matching. If this is indeed the case, I would recommend replacing the `=` equality operator with the `ALIKE` operator e.g.

```
"...WHERE [OA_Name] ALIKE '%' + @searchTerm + '%'";
```

The problem with the `LIKE` operator is that the Access database engine (ACE, Jet, whatever) uses different wildcard characters depending on so-called [ANSI Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0). Presumably you are using ANSI-92 Query Mode by implication of using SqlOleDb (but would you have known for sure?)

The advantage of `ALIKE` is that is uses the same 'Standard' wildcard characters regardless of ANSI Query Mode, being `%` for multiple characters and `_` for a single character.

Answer (score 1):

try using [SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
 command.CommandText = "SELECT [OA_Name] FROM [Operating_Authority_Table] WHERE [OA_Name] LIKE '%"+ searchTerm +"%'";
```

Comment: I have used both = and LIKE and both worked for me when i tried to do the full string matching.